# Trying to find which button was clicked, and pushing the result to DB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So here's my JS script, in my head tag:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".chooseMood").click(function(){
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');


                    $.ajax({

                        url: 'demosys.php',
                        data: {mood: $( '#id' ).val(),
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#mood').html(data);   
                        }
                    });
                });

            }); 
            </script>
```

HTML that has the buttons:

```
<div class = "chooseMood">
                    <button type="submit" name="happy" id = "happy" value="happy_btn_was_clicked">
                        <img src="Images/happy.png" />
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" name="sad" id="sad" value="sad_btn_was_clicked">
                        <img src="Images/sad.jpg" />
                    </button>
                    <script>
                     $('#happy').click(function() {
                         $("#sad").hide();
                     });

                    $('#sad').click(function() {
                         $("#happy").hide();
                     });                         
                    </script>


                </div>
```

php file:

```
<?php
function submitMood($mood){

  $db_connection = new mysqli(/////);
  if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Connection Error!";
    return;
  }


  $recentMood = mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM `DemoUser` ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1'");

  $today = date('Y-m-d');



  if($recentMood['date'] != $today){
     mysqli_query($db_connection, "INSERT INTO DemoUser (Mood, date) VALUES('$mood' , NOW())");
     echo "Mood recorded!";
  }

  else{


  echo "Mood already recorded.";
  }
}
submitMood($_GET['mood']);
?>
```

I am trying to find out which button was clicked. Each button is associated with a mood, and I want to insert that mood into the database after the click. Right now, my moods aren't being added to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an ID, just get the value of the button using `this`

```
 $(".chooseMood button").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault(); /* prevent form submit*/
     var mood = $(this).attr('value');
     $.ajax({
         url: 'demosys.php',
         data: {
             mood: mood,
             success: function (data) {
                 $('#mood').html(data);
             }
         });
     });
});
```

Comment: I changed it to your code, and still nothing. I put in a test echo to appear after I connect to my database(triple checked to make sure it is correct), and even that isn't appearing. The php file is still the same.

Comment: use browser console network tab to see if request is made and if so inspect it deeper. If not add some console logging inside the click handler (or even an alert) to make sure event is registering. Also make sure no other errors are thrown in console

Comment: Get this error:GET http://****/final/demosys.php?mood=happy 500

(Internal Server Error) jquery.js:8706send jquery.js:8706x.extend.ajax jquery.js:8136(anonymous function) demo:18x.event.dispatch jquery.js:5095v.handle

Comment: ok so need to debug the server code and you should add some error handling to the ajax also. Make sure data posted in console is what you expect it to be

Comment: Sorry, by server code you are talking about the demosys.php file that pushes the stuff into the database correct? And the error handling in the ajax is just making sure that it is a string being sent correct?

Comment: yes regarding server.. looks like you haven't converted your first query... ajax error ...read ajax docs

Comment: I think I got it. Just a stupid semi-colon. Thank you so much for dealing with me. Edit: and you were right about the first query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you code is working fine but there is a little problem there. Chnage your code to:

```
data: { mood: $('#' + id).val() },
```

you should concat **'#'** + **id** then read its value. and your selector is wrong too:

```
$(".chooseMood button").click(...
```